# Express +EJS not passing results to html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, express

I am currently trying out this twitter hashtag wall using the twitter API : https://www.codewall.co.uk/how-to-build-a-twitter-hashtag-viewing-tool-tutorial/  .

My problem is that i followed every step from the tutorial, but am not getting any tweets in my index.ejs page. My API credentials are right as when i tried getting tweets in the console it worked, but I don't know why the tweets output is not being passed to the index page and when i click "analyze" to search for tweet hashtag the page just reloads with no output.

**Here is my server.js file:**

```html
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const twit = require("twit")
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')


app.get('/index', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index',  {welcomeMessage: "Welcome to my app."})
  })

app.post('/', function (req, res) {

    if (req.body.hashtag !== null) {

        let Twitter = new twit({
            consumer_key: '',
            consumer_secret: '',
            access_token: '',
            access_token_secret: '',
            // timeout_ms: 60 * 1000, // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
            // strictSSL: true, // optional - requires SSL certificates to be valid.
        });
        Twitter.get('search/tweets', {
            q: req.body.hashtag,
            count: 1, // how many tweets to return
            result_type: "mixed" 
          }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('caught error', err.stack)
          }).then(function (result) {
             console.log('data', result.data);
          });

        Twitter.get('search/tweets', {
            q: req.body.hashtag, // use the user posted hashtag value as the query
            count: 100,
            result_type: "mixed"

        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('caught error', err.stack)
            res.render('index', {
                hashtag: null,
                twitterData: null,
                error: err.stack
            });
        }).then(function (result) {
            // Render the index page passing in the hashtag and the Twitter API results
            res.render('index', {
                hashtag: req.body.hashtag,
                twitterData: result.data,
                error: null

            });
            console.log('render') //whole code is done
        });
    }
    
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Node listening on port 3000')
})
```

**Here is my index.ejs file:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", charset="utf-8">
    <title>Twitter Hashtag Viewer</title>
    <link href="/css/style.css"  type="text/css" >
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
        type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form mb-2 mt-2"> 
        <fieldset>
            <form action="/" method="post">
                <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="hashtag" placeholder="eg. #100DaysOfCode" required type="text">
                <input type="submit" value="Analyze!">
                </div>
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </div>   
    

    <div class="container-fluid">

    </div>
    <% if("hashtag" !== null){ %>
    <h3>All popular tweets for <%- "hashtag" %></h3>

    <% } %>

<div id="tweets"></div>

    <% if("twitterData" !== null){ %>

       
    <script>
        let twitterData  = <%- JSON.stringify("twitterData") %>;
        let tweetHTML = '<div class="row">';
        for (let index = 0; index < twitterData.statuses; index++) {
            var createdDateTime = new Date(twitterData.statuses[index].created_at).toUTCString();

            tweetHTML += '<div class="col-sm-4"><div class="card mb-3">' +
                '<div class="card-body">' +
                '<h5 class="card-title">@' + twitterData.statuses[index].user.screen_name + '</h5>' +
                '<h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">' + twitterData.statuses[index].user.name + '</h6>' +
                '<p class="card-text">' + twitterData.statuses[index].text + '<</p>' +
                '<p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + twitterData.statuses[index].retweet_count + ' <i class="fa fa-heart" style="color:red;" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + twitterData.statuses[index].favorite_count + '</p>' +
                
              //  '<a class="card-link" href="#">Another link</a>' +
                '<p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Created on '+createdDateTime.toString()+' </small></p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';
        }
        tweetHTML += '</div>';

        var tweetsContainer = document.getElementById("tweets");
        tweetsContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', tweetHTML);
        
    </script>
    <% } %>



   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! `Twitter.get(...).catch(function(err) {...}).then(function(result) {...})` does not work: If the Twitter request fails, both `catch` and `then` functions are executed, leading to `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` errors. Use `Twitter.get(...).then(function(result) {...}, function(err) {...})` instead.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. However it still does not show the tweets in my index web page and only in the console.

Comment: I see your error but I won't tell you right now. Instead, I want you to go to the tutorial link you provided, copy/paste the whole code from there in your codebase, see if it works. If it does work, you then copy piece by piece and compare to your code, see what's the difference, you will understand why your code isn't running as expected.

Comment: Tried copy/pasting the whole code, but it does not work.

Comment: It worked! I will copy and paste it piece by piece to compare why my old code was not working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I broke it when trying to figure out where the mistake was and am struggling to fix it again, can you tell me where the error is?